# Exporting a dictionary discretely

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to export a dictionary discretely? By discretely I mean that each (key, value) will be exported independently of the other values, and will be able to be imported independently.

For example, if I have this object in a module:

```
const obj = {one: 'two', three: 'four'}
```

I want to be able to import its values from another file like this:

```
import {one} from './module'
import {three} from './module'
```

But obviously, I *don't* want to explicitly export each key/value manually.

Comment: If you export the whole object, the `import` statements will do what you expect.

Comment: How so? If I export the object by name, I have to import it by name. If I export it as a default object, I have to do "import default". How can I just import the relevant key and not the whole object?

Comment: "_But obviously, I don't want to explicitly export each key/value manually._": That's not how ES modules work. If you want to _statically_ [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) a name, you must also _statically_ [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) the name.

Comment: If this is something you are encountering frequently, you can create (or perhaps find a plugin for) a build tool to help you emit source code that meets your requirements (without writing everything directly using your fingers on the keyboard).